# Beautifulsoup get the value of hrefs separated by commas

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```
sup2 = soup2.find_all("div", {"class": "xxxxxxx"})
```

When i use find_all over a div i get the following result

```
<div class="xxxxxxx" data-reactid="37"><a href="/zz/aa">aa </a>, <a href="/xx/yy">bb </a></div>
```

how to get href between these two commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the `Tag` elements in `sup2` and select the 'href' attribute, eg:

```
hrefs = [a['href'] for tag in sup2 for a in tag.find_all('a')]
```

Using css selectors:

```
hrefs = [tag['href'] for tag in soup2.select("div.xxxxxxx a")]
```

Comment: Updated, try again.